# Highchart - Column range as arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am integrating column range chart but I want the column to appear as an arrow. The arrow could be facing downward / upwards based on if the value is increased or decreased.

I can't seem to find any workaround to achieve this.

Below is a reference picture of what I am trying to achieve..

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: [
            [-9.9, 10.3],
            [-8.6, 8.5],
            [-10.2, 11.8],
            [-1.7, 12.2],
            [-0.6, 23.1],
            [3.7, 25.4],
            [6.0, 26.2],
            [6.7, 21.4],
            [3.5, 19.5],
            [-1.3, 16.0],
            [-8.7, 9.4],
            [-9.0, 8.6]
        ]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render triangles by using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`.

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

But I think the easiest option will be using a scatter series with triangle markers to achive this. Check the following config and demo:

```
{
  type: 'scatter',
  showInLegend: false,
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'triangle-down',
    fillColor: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
    radius: 9
  },
  states: {
    inactive: {
      opacity: 1,
    },
  },
  data: [{
      x: 9,
      y: -1.3
    },
    {
      x: 10,
      y: -8.7
    },
    {
      x: 11,
      y: -9.0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3rokf4aw/